# Strange font rendering issues with Firefox

Tags: css, macos, firefox, fonts, rendering

[image]

These are placeholders in input fields with the same 'computed style' (says at least the inspector) in Firefox but why do they look different? This problem is Firefox only. Has anyone seen something like this before?

Thanks.

Comment: What browsers are the two screenshots from? Two different versions of Firefox or one Firefox and another browser? Can you show us some code or point us to a URL?

Comment: Text is an element of web design that you can't reasonably expect to control.  Each browser has subtle differences in how they render text.

Comment: This is actually even the same window in Firefox and the Inspector (or whatever that thing is called in FF) tells me they have the same computed css values :|